# android multipart php post error

Tags: php, android, http-post, multipart

I'm trying to upload file from android to server.
I used php for server. This isn't working and I can not find why. Please help me.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://ganji.snucse.org/upload.php");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();  
            reqEntity.addPart("imageFile", new FileBody(img1_file));
            try {
                reqEntity.addPart("imageTitle", new StringBody("imageTitle"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
             post.setEntity(reqEntity);

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

this is java code and

```
  1 <?php
  2
  3 $uploaddir = './uploads/';
  4 $file = basename($_FILES['imageFile']['imageTitle']);
  5 $uploadfile = $uploaddir.$file;
  6
  7
  8 echo 'Debugging Info:';
  9 print_r($_FILES);
 10
 11 print "</pre>";
 12
 13 ?>
```

this is php code

This doesn't work. I can not understand why. Please help me.

Comment: here are you post method in php code to take value.

Comment: Are you getting specific exception? if any post your LogCat output with the StackTrace

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I have in my working version is:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name']));
```